# RAmazonS3 connection authentication issue - HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

Tags: r, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use the `listBuckets` function from the [RAmazonS3 package](https://github.com/duncantl/RAmazonS3) but getting `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`.

First I'm setting the authentication options as described in [the manual](http://www.omegahat.org/RAmazonS3/s3amazon.pdf):

```
options(AmazonS3 = c('login' = 'secret'))
```

I replaced `login` with my access key ID (20 characters), and `secret` with my secret access key (40 characters).  When I run `listBuckets()`, I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xmlSApply") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlSApply' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

It's not returning any data, so it must not be connecting properly.  Digging into it, there is a `getURL` call within `listBuckets`.  The output of that line is:

```
* About to connect() to proxy proxyname.domain.com port xx (#0)
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx... * connected
* Connected to proxyname.domain.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port xx (#0)
> GET http://s3.amazonaws.com HTTP/1.1
Host: s3.amazonaws.com
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Date: Fri, 12 Sep 2014 09:02:41 EDT
Authorization: AWS [login]:[unknown 27-character code]=

< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< x-amz-request-id: [unknown 16-character code]
< x-amz-id-2: [unknown 64-character code]
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 12 Sep 2014 13:02:40 GMT
< Server: AmazonS3
< Cache-Control: proxy-revalidate
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host proxyname.domain.com left intact
```

**Any ideas where I'm going wrong?**

I'm not sure what value to use for `login`, so I've also tried my AWS account name, my AWS account user name, and literally 'login', but get a similar error.

Before finding the RAmazonS3 package, I was starting to write my own S3api functions using the [AWS Command Line Interface](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).  I was able to successfully list the buckets and their objects when calling the AWS CLI from R.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.3  bitops_1.0-6    RAmazonS3_0.1-5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4 tools_3.1.1  XML_3.98-1.1
```

Comment: It could be out of date; i am not sure as i am not the author of the package. Another package you can try would be the [AWSConnect](http://github.com/lalas/awsConnect) package, that I had put together that should allow u to do basic operation with S3 and EC2. Let me know if solve ur problem or experience any issue; as this package is still in beta form...

Comment: Thank you @Lalas.  Using `s3.ls()` from your package worked with no issues.

Comment: @Lalas, if you submit your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to repeat what's in the comment above; i have noticed that most of the R-packages that connected to AWS service were out of date. So i have created a new package [AWSConnect](http://github.com/lalas/awsConnect) that allows a user to do most basic operations with S3 and EC2. In that package, the function `s3.ls()` is designed to list the bucket on S3.

Please feel free to use it, and report any bugs/request/issues

Answer (score 1):

The package works in most cases:

login = AWS secret key

secret = AWS secret access key

Example: 
markus_test is a new created bucket with no public permission

```
auth <- c("AKIAJN6VFFXXXXXXXXXX" ="d95ij4uy0i6n+auvhwLLP6VQiz27OdXXXXXXXXXX")
listBucket("markus_test", auth)`
Key        LastModified                             ETag Size
1 rmr2_example.R 2014-09-15 23:38:48 c7f4544cf972bed52fa84164cf2505bf 1248
                                                      Owner.ID Owner.DisplayName
1 2a22982b6e7216f42abd2e8848f07a8ada0b1c11318dc8331aee068f29b7765d       markusataws
StorageClass
1     STANDARD
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale: 
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RAmazonS3_0.1-5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.4   RCurl_1.95-4.3 tools_3.1.1    XML_3.98-1
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying the correct login and secret values.  I'm still unable to get `RAmazonS3` to work though.

Comment: Can you please check the user permission in AWS IAM. Based on the first line of your question I assume that your user does not have S3 read permission.

Comment: The user (me) has read permission for some buckets but not others.  Using the AWS CLI directly or the `awsConnect` package from @Lalas, I can correctly read the buckets/objects that I have permission to read.

Comment: do you copy&paste or type your keys? we sometimes see issues with wrong characters due to copy&paste. Another idea :-)